# PHP dealing with files

Tags: php, file, special-characters

im' trying to make a `file based article system` and i want the folders to be my categories and files inside it to be the actual articles. But sometimes i need some special characters in my folder/file name(`\/:*?"`,and actually i'm interested just in double quotes and question mark). Is there a way to do the trick...something like `&amp;` is in html or something like this. thanks

Comment: Why not give the files sanitised names, and store a mapping from filename to display name somewhere?

Comment: hmm...i'm not sure i understand, can you give me a detailed answer please? if the user, when he creates the file, just puts the title(in the form field) like this: 'how are you?' what should i do then?(what my code should do?)

Comment: What you are proposing is not a good design. If you must use files (rather than a database) you could consider using either GUIDs for filenames or some sanitized version of the title, or a hash of it, and then store the title on the first line, for example. Even this has problems: what about if two articles have the same title? What happens if the title is changed? What about locking and concurrency?

I am guessing you are doing this to teach yourself rather than a real system. Teach yourself databases whilst you are doing it, it's worthwhile!

Comment: i used mysql for years, but from what i know the "actual files" + xml are more SEO friendly

Comment: kmunky: not true at all. Actual _file names_ are sometimes considered better for SEO, but that has _NOTHING_ to do with where the files are actually stored. That's your webserver at work.

Comment: Search engines can't look in to how the files are presented on your server. For all they know, there's a gnome sitting on the other end typing it out on an old Commodore.

Comment: Yep. If you're talking about URLs, then that has nothing to do with how your files are stored (if you're using them for back-end storage). Look at your `.htaccess` for details of how to do that. Plenty of sites have a SQL back-end and present nice-looking URLs (look at WordPress for example).

Comment: ok, so this is a new chapter for me, i have read nothing about this by now so i have to do some research, can you recommend me some articles or what should i read about? thanks guys, i'm pretty excited to hear about this design

Comment: Assuming you're using Apache. This is a classic on mod_rewrite: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only few special characters which aren't allowed in file names. so keep your own insanitized sequence for those characters. For instance, replace all '?' with '#quest' before creating files and so. Do the reverse when you read them, aint this good? Insanitized means some combination of characters that we don't type usually like '#quest'.

Comment: this is an interesting idea, but how my url will look like then?and how friendly for search engines is that?

Comment: when you read the file just do the reverse of it, like replace all '#quest' to '?' so your URLs will be fine. I think thats what you asked?

Comment: oh yeah, right...actually it's very easy ;) it's all based on "encode"/"decode", thanks @pMan

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Your operating system could support such file names, but it doesn't seem to.

There isn't a simple way for you to do something easy like `&amp;` for this. You could store the real filename, or make a conversion table such that something like `_____questionmark_____` converted into that symbol or something silly like that, but then you run into problems with that particular string.

Fundamentally though, you should store the title separately from the file itself. A database would be an appropriate location.

At a deeper level, if you're asking a question like this, I think it's safe to say that allowing users to specify filenames on your system is likely to be a large security risk.

Comment: those users will have administrator privileges(just a few users). what i don't understand is this mixed file and database...

Comment: It's simple: You can't reasonably store the title you want to use as a valid filename, so you have to store it somewhere else. Your titles won't generate valid URLs either. You might do well to look up various "slug" functions for converting strings into URL friendly formats. As a bonus, they can be stored on the disk with that as the filename too.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `.htaccess` file to pass the "filename" as an argument to your PHP script. Subsequently have the script look up the article in a database lookup table that points to the article file.